# Is this simple code about python if-else statement wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

```
grade = 0.0
grade = input("Please enter your gpa")
    def grade_give(grade):
        if grade > 0.9:
            print("A")  
        elif grade > 0.8 and grade < 0.9 :
            print("B")
        elif grade >0.7 and grade < 0.8:
            print ("C")
        elif grade >0.6 and grade <0.7:
            print ("D")
        elif grade >0.5 and grade <0.6:
            print ("E")
        elif grade >0.4 and grade <0.3:
           print ("F")
        else:
           print("Bad score")

grade_give(grade)
```

The error which appears is File "/Users/pradyu/Desktop/py.py/function.py", line 4, in grade_give
    if grade > 0.9:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Answer (score 1):

The input from input is a string . Convert it to float.

```
grade = input("Please enter your gpa")
grade = float(grade)
#carry on
```

or do this in the function

```
def func(grade):
    grade = float(grade)
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: `raw_input` is not used at all in the code in the question. `input` in Python 3.x returns a string.

Comment: sorry, python-2.7 you know :-)